# Return object property if existing else set initial value

Tags: javascript

Are there any other cleaner approach for my code? Looks my code isn't readable.

```
const materials = entry.materials.flat().map(c => ({
  ...c,
  ...(c.quality_id ? { quality_id: c.quality_id } : { quality_id: null }),
  ...(c.quantity_used
    ? { quantity_used: c.quantity_used }
    : { quantity_used: 0 }),
  ...(c.remarks ? { remarks: c.remarks } : { remarks: "" }),
}));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to spread the objects other than the first `c`.

```
const materials = entry.materials.flat().map(c => ({
    ...c,
    quality_id: c.quality_id || null,
    quantity_used: c.quantity_used || 0,
    remarks: c.remarks || ''
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

With some destructuring:

```
const materials = entry.materials.flat().map(
 ({ quality_id, quantity_used, remarks, ...rest }) => ({
    quality_id: quality_id || null,
    quantity_used: quantity_used || 0,
    remarks: remarks || '',
    ...rest
  })
);
```